# How to validate the inclusion of a list that contain two words

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I just figured out how to validate the inclusion of my select. However I have one problem that have risen. I'm unable to figure out how to validate it, if one of the values contain two words or more.

Take for example:

```
validates_inclusion_of :possibility, :in => %w(yes maybe no)
```

it would work perfectly. Yet if I have two, three words say:

```
validates_inclusion_of :job_possibility, :in => %w(yes please maybe not no thank you)
```

it wouldn't work. I've tried adding them into brackets etc. But been able to figure it out. Anybody know how to make this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it by using `%W` instead of `%w` to achieve the required result. As `%W` supports String interpolation, you can easily implement the two words, three words, etc.

Using `%W` :

```
validates_inclusion_of :job_possibility, :in => %W(yes please #{"maybe not"} no #{"thank you"})
```

-Or-

you could just specify the array directly:

```
validates_inclusion_of :job_possibility, :in => ["yes", "please", "maybe not", "no", "thank you"]
```

For example:

In IRB,

```
 > job_possibility = %W(yes please #{"maybe not"} no #{"thank you"})
 ## => ["yes", "please", "maybe not", "no", "thank you"] 
 > job_possibility = ["yes", "please", "maybe not", "no", "thank you"]
 ## => ["yes", "please", "maybe not", "no", "thank you"]
```